# Extract network packets protocol using PCAP.Net

Tags: c#, networking, pcap.net

In order to parse network traffic I'm using `PCAP.Net` (I run splitcap on a given PCAP file and using PCAP.Net to extract communication data from the resulted bin files).

Is it possible to get the Protocol (HTTP, FTP etc.) being used in a specific packet (no based on port number) using PCAP.Net?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP and FTP protocols are recognized by ports. Content might help as well.

As far as I know, there's no other way to recognize such packets.

[Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net) can't give you the protocol of the packet because there isn't a way to do that.

You can guess the protocol similar to how Wireshark guesses it using ports, content and other packets.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was afraid that the only way to find  packets using protocols in non conventional port is by parsing / finding key words in its content.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is several years old, but using PCAP.net 1.0.2.76195 (several years old at the time of this writing), you can get it very simply like such

```
packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol
```

For example, reading an icmp packet like this

`Console.WriteLine(packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol.ToString())`

Shows this

```
InternetControlMessageProtocol
```

A TCP packet shows up as

```
Tcp
```